# Copying large files on the same disk - increasing the buffer

Tags: macos

I'm on OS X, and I'm copying a large amount of data from one partition to another.
Because of the nature of a magnetic disk, I feel this would go much faster if I can get 'cp' to use a huge buffer of a few hundred megs.

Is this easily possible at all? I'm copying several directories recursively.

Answer (score 0):

No matter what you do in between, shuffling data within solid-state memory chips, the processes of reading and writing a magnetic/mechanical disk, which requires physically moving pieces of metal, will take orders of magnitude more time, and there's no way to avoid that.

Comment: Well I figure if the disk reads 100 megs, moves the head, and then writes should be _much_ faster than doing this for every couple of kb's. This is very easily testable.

Comment: Random access is just faster that sequential access